# PLUS can't define in Google play service

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

Following error are  display i comiple the library file also but error is display i use compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'

[image]

help me i am new in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your build.gradle you should add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
```

Then you should run a Gradle build and then you will be able to import Plus into your class

Comment: Thanks @apmartin1991 save my day

Comment: No worries - Happy coding :)